# Xamarin forms асинхронный клик на Item

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, async-await

Есть асинхронный метод:

```
public Task<List<Address>> GetAllByStreet(string street)
{
      return db.QueryAsync<Address>(
                "SELECT DISTINCT House as Title, " +
                "NULL as Type, " +
                "NULL as Status, " +
                "0 as Visibility FROM Quest WHERE Street = ?", street);
}
```

Пытаюсь вызвать его при клике на Item в `ListView`:

```
private async void ListViewAddresses_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
   List<Address> allHouse = await dataBaseController.GetAllByStreet((e.Item as Address).Street);
}
```

Но метод не срабатывает. Хотя, если вызвать его в отдельном асинхронном методе, то все будет работать. Что не так?

Answer (score -1):

У вас нет инструкции о том, что вы хотите получить возврат вызова(callback).

GetAllByStreet должен так же содержать async/await.

async void дает инструкцию "запусти и не ломайся при ошибке", что может привести в совокупности к иллюзии "не работает".